# Transfering Data From CSV to XLS w/ python

Tags: python, list, csv, xls

I am looking to transfer data from a csv file to a template xls file. I would like to take the column in the csv file and insert them under specific headers in the xls file. Let's say I have data that looks like:

*example.csv*:

```
4/5/2015 13:34,Apples,73
4/5/2015 3:41,Cherries,85
4/6/2015 12:46,Pears,14
4/8/2015 8:59,Oranges,52
4/10/2015 2:07,Apples,152
4/10/2015 18:10,Bananas,23
4/10/2015 2:40,Strawberries,98
```

and I have headers that are on row #3 of the XLS file on sheet 2 that are:

*headers.xls*:

```
Date, Time, Type, Color, Count
```

I want to insert the .csv under these row #3 headers but they need to fit the column. Here I do not have information on color so it needs to be skipped.

Comment: Any code that you would like to share with your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

This provides several options for working with Excel using Python.

http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: My assumption is that I will bring in both the xls and the csv. Create a list of lists of the csv.... and then??

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. If you have some code that you can show and have specific questions about something that isn't working, or questions about optimizing it I'm sure someone will be able to help. For now, the core of your problem seems to lie in reading in a CSV file and writing it out as a Excel Workbook.